# How to efficiently change the basis of a 3-dimensional figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I'm actually rewriting a math textbook for my students. I wanted to show them that a basis isn't necessarily orthonormal. So I want to draw two figures with 2 different basisses.

I found some code for my first picture but I don't know how to change it in order to keep the same idea but with a different basis.
Here is the code of first picture:

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}

\newcommand{\Prho}{1.2}%
\newcommand{\Ptheta}{55}%
\newcommand{\Pphi}{60}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=5,
    tdplot_main_coords,
    axis/.style={->,black,thick},
    vector/.style={-stealth,black,ultra thick},
    vector guide/.style={dashed,lightgray,thick}]
    
    %standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    
    %tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\Prho}{\Ptheta}{\Pphi}
    
    %draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    
    %draw a vector from O to P
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (P);
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (0.3,0,0) node[sloped,midway,above=-0.1cm]{$\tiny\overrightarrow{OI}$} ;
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (0,0.3,0) node[sloped,midway,above=-0.1cm]{$\tiny\overrightarrow{OJ}$};
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (0,0,0.3) node[sloped,midway,above=-0.1cm]{$\tiny\overrightarrow{OK}$};
    
    %draw guide lines to components
    \draw[vector guide] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxy) -- (P);
    
    % Compute x,y,z
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PxCoord}{\Prho * sin(\Pphi) * cos(\Ptheta)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PyCoord}{\Prho * sin(\Pphi) * sin(\Ptheta)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PzCoord}{\Prho * cos(\Pphi)}%
    
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxy) -- (Px) node [left, black]  {$x_a.\overrightarrow{OI}$};
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxy) -- (Py) node [above right, black] {$y_a.\overrightarrow{OJ}$};
    \draw[vector guide] (Pyz) -- (Pz) node [left, black]  {$z_a.\overrightarrow{OK}$};
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxz) -- (Pz);
    \draw[vector guide] (Px) -- (Pxz);
    \draw[vector guide] (Pyz) -- (Py);
    \draw[vector guide] (P) -- (Pxz);
    \draw[vector guide] (P) -- (Pyz);
    \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (Py) {};
    \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (Px) {};
    \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (Pz) {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border= 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\newcommand{\Prho}{1.2}%
\newcommand{\Ptheta}{55}%
\newcommand{\Pphi}{60}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=5,
    tdplot_main_coords,
    axis/.style={->,black,thick},
    vector/.style={-stealth,black,ultra thick},
    vector guide/.style={dashed,lightgray,thick},
    x={(-1.4cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(-0.1cm,-0.3cm)}, z={(0.1cm,1cm)},
    ]
    
    %standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    
    %tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\Prho}{\Ptheta}{\Pphi}
    
    %draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    
    %draw a vector from O to P
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (P);
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (0.3,0,0) node[sloped,midway,above=-0.1cm]{$\tiny\overrightarrow{OI}$} ;
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (0,0.3,0) node[sloped,midway,above=-0.1cm]{$\tiny\overrightarrow{OJ}$};
    \draw[vector] (O) -- (0,0,0.3) node[sloped,midway,above=-0.1cm]{$\tiny\overrightarrow{OK}$};
    
    %draw guide lines to components
    \draw[vector guide] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxy) -- (P);
    
    % Compute x,y,z
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PxCoord}{\Prho * sin(\Pphi) * cos(\Ptheta)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PyCoord}{\Prho * sin(\Pphi) * sin(\Ptheta)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PzCoord}{\Prho * cos(\Pphi)}%
    
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxy) -- (Px) node [left, black]  {$x_a.\overrightarrow{OI}$};
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxy) -- (Py) node [above right, black] {$y_a.\overrightarrow{OJ}$};
    \draw[vector guide] (Pyz) -- (Pz) node [left, black]  {$z_a.\overrightarrow{OK}$};
    \draw[vector guide] (Pxz) -- (Pz);
    \draw[vector guide] (Px) -- (Pxz);
    \draw[vector guide] (Pyz) -- (Py);
    \draw[vector guide] (P) -- (Pxz);
    \draw[vector guide] (P) -- (Pyz);
    \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (Py) {};
    \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (Px) {};
    \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (Pz) {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

[image: Axis with unit vectors]

[image: Skewed axis with unit vectors]